# assigning a char to a string

Tags: c, recursion

I'm stuck here trying to understand why this assignement can't work in this way in C. What I'm trying to do is substitute all space occurrences with underscore char. (output: Hi_from_Synchronyze)
I saw that the problem comes when I try to do this..

```
s[n]='_';
```

the complete code is this one

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *underscore(char *s, int n);

int main()
{
    printf("%s", underscore("Hi from Synchronyze", 0));
    return 0;
}

char *underscore(char *s, int n)
{
    if(s[n]=='\0')
        return s;
    else {
        if(s[n]==' ') {
            s[n]='_';
            return underscore(s, n+1);
        }
        else return underscore(s, n+1);
    }
}
```

I'd like to know what's going on behinde and why this happens, not the solution.
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: `"Hi from Synchronyze"`. That is a constant string. It is readonly. It cannot be modified.

Comment: String literal can not be changed. change to `printf("%s", underscore((char[]){"Hi from Synchronyze"}, 0));`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY that's a cast right?

Comment: It's [Compound Literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal).

Answer (score 2):

String literals are read-only, so you can't assign to them.

Make a mutable copy of the string first, something like:

```
char text[] = "Hi from Synchronyze";
printf("%s", underscore(text, 0));
```